# Using Google Maps Step by Step Navigation inside Flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I want to navigate from the user's location to the destination inside my Flutter app. There are some packages that allow showing the direction but not navigating like the image below. An alternative way is to use Google Maps in a web view in my app which is not my favorite. I need a way to show the suggested route to the destination and assist the driver to it step by step.

[image]

Comment: Hey did you find anything?

Comment: @AdilShinwari Unfortunately nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for using direction in google map you should enable billing account, it's cost you about $500 per 100K direction request.

but you can use $200 per month for free, around 40K direction request.

[you can see the pricing here.](https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/?_ga=2.168123809.1232495763.1645887106-1910749787.1645887106#pricing-grid)

[Google map flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)

Comment: Thank you, but how is it possible to use it in my app?

Comment: I added package link in answer.

Comment: That package does not support turn-by-turn navigation.

Comment: for turn-by-turn navigation, you will need the google navigation SDK. 
here is the link to the docs https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/navigation

it is a special service for ride-hailing services so you will have to contact Google sales team.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but currently there is no SDK available with in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the turn-by-turn navigation by using this package

[flutter_mapbox_navigation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mapbox_navigation)

It works with MapBox SDK